# assigning click method to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am creating an array & assigning the value to each index in a function through variables.

I also want to attach a jquery click method to each variable. However, I am getting 'undefined' in return when the click method is called.

```
var i = 0;
var eCreditTransactions = new Array(6);         // 6 members created which will be recycled
function abc()
{
    addingElements (i); 
}

                /* **** THE FOLLOWING IS THE PROBLEM AREA **** */
$(eCreditTransactions[i]).click (function ()                    // if user clicks on the transaction box
{
    creditTransactionSlideIn (eCreditTransactions[0], 150);     //another function called
});

                /* **** this is the function being called in the first function above **** */
function addingElements (arrayIndex)                    // func called from within the 'createCreditTransaction()' func
{
    eCreditTransactions[i] = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass("cCreditTransaction").appendTo(eCreditSystem);
    $(eCreditTransactions[i]).attr ('id', ('trans' + i));
    $(eCreditTransactions[i]).html ('<div class="cCreditContainer"><span class="cCreditsNo">-50</span>&nbsp;<img class="cCurrency" src="" alt="" /></div><span class="cCloseMsg">Click box to close.</span><div class="dots"></div><div class="dots"></div><div class="dots"></div>');
    creditTransactionSlideOut (eCreditTransactions[i], 666);                    // calling slideOut animation
    counterFunc ();
    return i++;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is really poor.

Comment: Agreed, I had to copy specific lines from my editor. Next time will put in an extra effort on the indentation.

Comment: Please do it now using the _edit_ function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it looks like each element you're adding to the array has a classname (cCreditTransaction) you can hookup the click events using something like

```
$(document).delegate(".cCreditTransaction", "click", function() {
   // code to fire on click goes here.
});
```

or in jQuery 1.7+ you can use `.on` instead of `.delegate`

You don't then need to hook up *n* events, but just one event that matches all items in the selector (in your case, the class name)

You should also change `$(document)` to a container element that has an Id, so that the DOM traversal to find the classes is trimmed down as much as possible. Why? Because finding elements by class name is a relatively expensive procedure, as opposed to finding tags or even better, an ID.

Comment: Thank you SpaceBison. Took me a while to figure out the methods but it appears, '.on' & '.one' are the answer.

I also had to insert the code within the 'addingElements(i)' function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cCreditTransaction").click(function() {
      //do what you want on click event
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Sudhir, it didn't work though. I think I know why, the class '.cCreditTransaction' is not created until the function is called (by user action), so the document.ready isn't the solution. I am confused as then the following should work:
    $(".cCreditTransaction").click(function() {
      //do what you want on click event
      });

Comment: You didnt win the cake this time @Sudhir but thank you for directing me in the right direction. It was only after reading your code did it start falling into place that one of the issues was the position of the code within the function. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there should be a loop in this part:

```
function abc()
{
  addingElements (i); 
}
```

there is a call to addingElements, and an 'i' parameter being passed, but 'i' is at that moment still defined as 0.
it should say something like

```
function abc()
{
     for (i=0;i<=7;i++)
     {
         addingElements (i); 
     }
}
```

Comment: No need as I only need one variable to be filled in the array upon one action by the user. The idea is that at the max, there should only be 6 members of an array, after 6 are used up, they should be recycled.